# grails 2.4.4 not use jsp page

Tags: jsp, grails

grails 2.4.4 not use *.jsp page,
grails 1.x is ok

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

URI:/aaaa.jspClass:org.apache.jasper.JasperExceptionMessage:Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file:

How to set up?

Comment: Not able to understand what you are trying to say, please elaborate more !

Comment: I want to use the JSP page in GRAILS,In previous versions of JSP pages can be added directly,But now the version of 2.4.4 has been reported to add fault.

Answer (score 0):

web.xml

> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
>     <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

Add url mapping.